# How to make an image height resize accordingly to the size of the contents below it, in a fixed size container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I understand this could be a hard one, I have 10+ years working with HTML, but I can't find a solution that doesn't involve working with complicated calculations with Javascript.

I have a fixed-size container divided in two, so the container has a top half and a bottom half. The top half has an image. The bottom half has text. What I want is that the image and the text occupy all the available space. If the text is short, there is more space available for the image. If the text is larger, the image is smaller, dynamically. I've added a couple of screenshots to illustrate what I want. In all cases, they occupy 100% of the available vertical space of the fixed-size container.

[image: Image with one line of text below it]

[image: Image with multiple lines of text below it]

Comment: This would follow the principle of responsive design. Give me a little bit  and I'll have a working answer for you

Comment: I got distracted but it appears that other users have offered very good suggestions. digitaldouble provided an elegant css only solution using either tables or flexboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pure css approach

You can probably try using `display: table-row`

https://jsfiddle.net/4h37fv7o/

Try and modify the length of the text at the bottom and see the image resize.

There are some caveats but it works.

Alternatively, you can use flexbox albeit, using background image:

https://jsfiddle.net/kdm0amsx/1/

Comment: This is an elegant pure css option. I also like the flex box usage

Comment: Thanks! I liked this approach the most because it's pure css. I improved it by using a max-width and centering the image.

Answer (score 3):

with little js/jquery code you can calculate the height of your container and the text, then resize the image!

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/L42hguqw/2/

using JQUERY:

```
var resizeUI = function(){
        var container = $('.container').eq(0);
        var textFrame = $('.container .textFrame');
        var maxH = container.innerHeight();
        var textH = textFrame.outerHeight();
        $('.container .imageFrame').height(parseInt(maxH-textH,10)).show();
    };
```

**css:**

```
div.container{
    background: #BB0000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.imageFrame{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
div.imageFrame img{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

div.textFrame{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: #333;
    color: #DDD;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageFrame">
        <img src="http://www.conservatoryweb.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/iStock_000011293178XSmallPaulMaguire.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="textFrame">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS + CSS calc to get this affect. You will want to use JS to get the height of the text and apply a cal to the image height to get it to scale appropiatly

```
calc("100% - " + paragraphHeightVariable + "px - 2em")
```

the 2em is to account for the padding of the paragraph tag. The example below uses jQuery to get the paragraph height but you can use the vanillajs library to get it to.

```js
$(".container").each(function (a) {
    var $container = $(this);
    var $image = $container.children("img");
    var $p = $container.children("p");
    $image.css("height", "calc(100% - " + $p.height() + "px - 2em)");
    console.log($image.css("height"), $p.height());

});
```

```css
.container {
    width:400px;
    height:450px;
    background-color:grey;
}
.container p {
    background-color:purple;
}
.container img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400/" />
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400/" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et mollis leo. Nunc vel finibus tortor. Nam suscipit quam purus, a cursus nulla efficitur non. Integer cursus arcu vel libero blandit efficitur. In at ligula placerat, mattis lacus semper, convallis lorem.
    </p>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/400/" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et mollis leo. Nunc vel finibus tortor. Nam suscipit quam purus, a cursus nulla efficitur non. Integer cursus arcu vel libero blandit efficitur. In at ligula placerat, mattis lacus semper, convallis lorem.Donec consectetur maximus mauris, egestas sollicitudin nunc imperdiet sit amet. Suspendisse ut consequat magna. In at eros mollis, malesuada arcu sit amet, imperdiet orci. Mauris vitae augue id nisi vulputate ultrices. Morbi a ipsum lacinia arcu consequat sollicitudin ut quis mauris. Quisque est dui, euismod non vestibulum sagittis, varius at elit. Maecenas facilisis tortor eget lorem aliquam, vel consequat lacus egestas. Nam vitae euismod nulla, in condimentum libero. Vivamus eget massa eros.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, probably the easiest way is to use JavaScript's element.getBoundingClientRect() function. That would necessitate placing your text inside its own relative division, then applying said function to calculate the height of your finished text (in pixels).
 Since you are using fixed dimensions for your main container division, you could then calculate and use the remaining space for your image. 
One or two tricky little algos necessary here maybe, like working out aspect ratios to match the height property.

Hopefully this helps; I'm not sure how complicated the approach you were trying to avoid was.

```
        <head>
<style>
    body{
        background: #111;
        color:      #d00;
    }   

    #mainContainerDiv{
            top:        20%;
            height:     49%;

            left:       30%;
            width:      40%;

            background: #c90;
            color:      #d00;

            position: absolute;     
    }       



    #image{
            top:        10%;
            height:     30%;

            left:       30%;
            width:      40%;

            background: #0d0;
            color:      #ddd;

            position: absolute;     
    }       



    #textAtBottom{
            bottom: 2%;
            /*height:       40%;*/

            left:       30%;
            width:      40%;

            background: #d00;
            color:      #eee;

            padding: 1%;
            position: absolute;     
    }
```

abc def ghi jkl abc def ghi jkl abc def ghi jkl abc def ghi jkl abc def ghi jkl abc def ghi jkl abc def ghi jkl abc def def ghi jkl lorem ipsum doradum etsum ichtum latinum

```
        <!-- <div id="image">     UNCOMMENT THIS WHEN YOU'RE READY
             </div> -->

    </div><!-- mainContainerDiv-->


    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById('mainContainerDiv');
        var ar = a.getBoundingClientRect();
        alert('Main container element is ' + ar.top + 'pixels from its containing element i.e. <body>');

        // alert(' und hauptBeinhalter Unten ist ' + ar.bottom ');
        // Bildis niedriger, so Teil ist ' + ar.height-ar.top + 'hoch total');


        var e = document.getElementById('textAtBottom');
        var x = e.getBoundingClientRect();

        alert('Text at Bottom starts ' + x.top + ' vertical pixels down from <body>');

        var numm = parseInt(x.top)-parseInt(ar.top);
        alert('sooooo, you got '+ numm + ' pixels of space above the text to squeeze in your image!!!');
    </script>
```